# Building a RGB art project. Having a hard time with finding the right, Switch fuction

Tags: led

Is there push button switch, always "ON" to circuit #1. Then when pushed "MOM" circuit #1 is off, circuit #2 is "ON"

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange.  Be sure to take the tour to get the most out of this site:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/Tour

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a SPDT switch with momentary or non-latching action.

Answer (score 0):

Now they call them MOM-ON, MOM-OFF and come in a variety of poles and throws.
e.g. https://www.digikey.com/products/en/switches/pushbutton-switches/199?k=&pkeyword=&FV=3ac0025%2Cffe000c7&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500

Often this is done with a very low cost MOM-ON switch and a D Flipflop to toggle.